# Webform Multi-step validation

Tags: forms, webforms

I have a multi-step/page webform. It works fine. I have on one page two date fields. One field must be on or after the other and thus I want some validation. No problem I followed the tutorial ( [How to add custom validation to a webform element?](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element) ) and have a basic validation code/module in place. Code:

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    $this->validateArrivalDate($form_state);
  }

  /**
   * Validate Arrival / Dept dates.
   */
  private function validateArrivalDate(FormStateInterface $formState) {

      $arrival_date = !empty($formState->getValue('arrival_date')) ? Html::escape($formState->getValue('arrival_date')) : NULL;
      $departure_date = !empty($formState->getValue('departure_date')) ? Html::escape($formState->getValue('departure_date')) : NULL;

      if (is_null($arrival_date) || is_null($departure_date) || strtotime($arrival_date) > strtotime($departure_date)){
        $formState->setErrorByName('arrival_date', t('Arrival date must be on or before departure date.'));
        $formState->setErrorByName('departure_date', t('Departure date must be on or after arrival date.'));
      }
  }
```

It seems to work fine if the page with the dates on is the first page/step, but if it is on step/page 3 it kicks up a validation error on the first page/step as soon as I click next. So presumably I need to check what step/page I am on. Thus I added:

```
private function validateArrivalDate(FormStateInterface $formState) {
    $page = $formState->get('current_page');
    if ($page[0] == "page3"){

      $arrival_date = !empty($formState->getValue('arrival_date')) ? Html::escape($formState->getValue('arrival_date')) : NULL;
      $departure_date = !empty($formState->getValue('departure_date')) ? Html::escape($formState->getValue('departure_date')) : NULL;

      if (is_null($arrival_date) || is_null($departure_date) || strtotime($arrival_date) > strtotime($departure_date)){
        $formState->setErrorByName('arrival_date', t('Arrival date must be on or before departure date.'));
        $formState->setErrorByName('departure_date', t('Departure date must be on or after arrival date.'));
      }
    }
  }
```

This however doesn't run the validation, I can put what I want on step/page 3, click next and it carries on to page 4. Would appreciate it if anyone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps, it needs to be `if ($form['progress']['#current_page'] == "page3"){`

Comment: @NoSssweat you are a star, I should have spotted that.